# How to train a constant model (regression) in Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm trying to train a linear regression model in Python (with sklearn), but with slopes equal to zero, i.e., a constant model h(x) = b (h: model, b: intercept).

Do you know any method in sklearn to accomplish this? (I'm familiar with LinearRegression but I couldn't find an answer there).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I don't think you need sklearn for that. Algebraically speaking and assuming your X matrix univariate that is solved by the mean of Y minus the mean of your X.

```
    b = y_train.mean() - X_train.mean()
```

Comment: Thank you. I know this works, but I was looking for a specific method where you would just flip an input. Anyways, that helps too ;)